# The operating system on this computer or its service level pack does not meet the minimum requirements for sql server 2014

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am trying to install MS SQL server 2008, but when I tried to execute the installation, an error popped up that says,

> The operating system on this computer or its service level pack does not meet the minimum requirements for SQL server 2014.

Why is it looking for system requirements for SQL server 2014 when I'm trying to install server 2008? I want to learn SQL server that's why I want to install it.

Comment: Maybe you downloaded the wrong installer?

Comment: i downloaded the sql server 2008 express installer.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 8 & Server 2012 are the minimum supported OS versions for SQL Server 2016 so you're out of luck.

See [Operating System Requirements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/install/hardware-and-software-requirements-for-installing-sql-server#TOP_Principal).